# java Thread-safe LRUCache implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, cache

What is best way to implement thread-safe LRUCache in java?
Please review this one.
Is there any better approach which can be taken here?

```
package cache;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class  LRUCache<K,V> {

    private  ConcurrentLinkedQueue<K> concurrentLinkedQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<K>();

    private  ConcurrentHashMap<K,V> concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>();

    private ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    private Lock readLock = readWriteLock.readLock();

    private Lock writeLock = readWriteLock.writeLock();

    int maxSize=0;

    public LRUCache(final int MAX_SIZE){
        this.maxSize=MAX_SIZE;
    }

    public V getElement(K key){

        readLock.lock();
        try {
        V v=null;
          if(concurrentHashMap.contains(key)){
              concurrentLinkedQueue.remove(key);
              v= concurrentHashMap.get(key);
                concurrentLinkedQueue.add(key);
          }


        return v;
        }finally{
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public V removeElement(K key){
         writeLock.lock();
         try {
        V v=null;
        if(concurrentHashMap.contains(key)){
        v=concurrentHashMap.remove(key);
            concurrentLinkedQueue.remove(key);
        }

        return v;
         } finally {
             writeLock.unlock();
         }
    }

    public V addElement(K key,V value){
        writeLock.lock();
        try {
        if(concurrentHashMap.contains(key)){
             concurrentLinkedQueue.remove(key);
        }
        while(concurrentLinkedQueue.size() >=maxSize){
             K queueKey=concurrentLinkedQueue.poll();
             concurrentHashMap.remove(queueKey);
        }
        concurrentLinkedQueue.add(key);
        concurrentHashMap.put(key, value);

        return value;
        } finally{
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Advice 1**

This implementation is not thread safe. For example, if two threads invoked `getElement(key1)` simultaneously, they may runs to `concurrentLinkedQueue.add(key)` at same times(they both performed delete and get, but delete will fail the second time or just do nothing), then two same keys will be added.

**Advice 2**

Maybe `capacity` is more suitable than `maxSize`.

**Advice 3**

`LinkedHashMap` is often used as LRU cache.

Comment: Why does the number 1 happen? Doesn't the key get removed and added? Isn't concurrent containers thread safe.

Comment: @422_unprocessable_entity the three operations inside if block is not atomic. If two threads running to `concurrentLinkedQueue.add(key);` at same times(they both performed delete and get, but delete will fail the second time or just do nothing), two same keys will be added.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Well done on catching it. :) Can you insert the explanation in the answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Advice 1**

```
public class  LRUCache<K,V>
```

You have *two* spaces between `class` and `LRUCache`.

**Advice 2**

`v=null`

In professional Java programming, it is customary to have a single space ***before*** and ***after*** each ***binary*** operator.

**Advice 3**

```
public V getElement(K key){

    readLock.lock();
    try { ... } ...
```

Looks strange to me. Why not have instead the following:

```
public V getElement(K key){
    readLock.lock();

    try { ... } ...
```

**Advice 4**

```
int maxSize=0;
```

First of all, I suggest you make it `private`. Also, there is no need to initialize member `int`s with zero, that is done by Java by default. Other fundamental types are initialized to zero too.

**Advice 5**

```
public LRUCache(final int MAX_SIZE)
```

It is idiomatic to name only constants with `UPPER CASE`. Constructor (and method) parameters are advised to be in `camelCase`.

**Advice 6**

```
private  ConcurrentHashMap<K,V> concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>();
```

You could omit type parameters in `new ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>` thanks to ***diamond inference***. Also, you could declare all the members instead of `maxSize` to `final`:

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<K,V> concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

**Advice 7**

```
ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>
```

It is also customary to have a single space ***after*** each comma character: `<K,_V>`.

**Advice 8**

`concurrentLinkedQueue` and `concurrentHashMap`. These are not the best possible names for the two data structures. Instead of naming them according to their type I instead suggest to name them according to what they do.

Answer (score 1):

#### Advice 1

Rename concurrentHashMap to internalCache

#### Advice 2

Rename concurrentLinkedQueue to trackingQueue

#### Advice 3

Declare using Queue Interface:

```
Queue<K> trackingQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
```

#### Advice 4

Your get API implementation is not thread safe as pointed out in one of the comments above.
You can do the getElement implementation as follows to make sure that a simultaneaous remove from queue for same element does not result in adding back duplicate element to queue:

```
public V getElement(K key){
  readLock.lock();
  try {
    V value = internalCache.get(key);
    if(value != null){
      if (trackingQueue.remove(key)) {
        trackingQueue.add(key);
      }
    }
    return value;
  } finally {
    readLock.unlock();
  }
}
```